# Cert storage and lookup

Tags: x509certificate

Working on cert related stuff and was wondering if there is a way to tag/hash/something in a unique way that could make lookup of a cert's parent signing cert faster than going through lookup of all the certs in folders? I'm looking for some kind of unambiguous and unique indexing method so that when I read a cert to validate it, I can extract information from some fields and quickly associate it with the parent cert to quickly resolve the chain assuming I have properly indexed the certs with that same unique key (index value could be used in filename or a database or other).

I noticed that on ubuntu when you look at /etc/ssl/certs there is a bunch of symlinks which look like perhaps a crc32 of some sort that links to the certs

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Mar  9  2016 e113c810.0 -> Certigna.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar  9  2016 e18bfb83.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     36 Mar  9  2016 e268a4c5.0 -> AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar  9  2016 e2799e36.0 -> GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar  9  2016 e36a6752.0 -> Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Mar  9  2016 e442e424.0 -> QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
```

I'm aware of the cert thumbprint/fingerprint but that isn't what I'm looking for and seems only to serve as a further validation of the cert contents itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hash of the issuer's public key. It is presented in leaf certificate as a prt of `Authority Key Identifier` certificate extension. It contains a hash calculated over issuer's public key. In CA certificate, this value is stored in `Subject Key Identifier`.

If AKI extension is missing, the only way to bind certificates in the chain is to use name match. `Issuer` field in leaf certificate must match `Subject` field of the issuer. However, if CA maintains multiple CA keys, there might be several CA certificates with the same subject, but with different keys. In this case, you will have to try each matching issuer candidate and attempt to validate the signature.

This means that you should maintain two indexes: by a hash of issuer's public key and issuer's `Subject` field to speed up certificate lookup.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I missed in reading the docs (that RFC is huge!)